# Adding a function as an array in a cell or range of cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

How do I add a formula configured as an array into a cell using VBA?

When I type the function directly into one cell it returns values into a range of cells.

Ex.
In cell N34 I type {=myFunction("datacollector";"nameOfVariable";"startDate";"endDate";TRUE)}
The function returns values in cells N34 to P59.

When, in VBA, I create the function string and try to insert it into a cell I get a run-time error.

I'm creating the function string without {}, and with data from other cells.

Code is:

```
tempStr = "=myFunction(""" & Sheet1.Cells(2,1) & """;""" & Sheet1.Cells(3,1) & """;""" & Sheet1.Cells(4,1) & """;""" & Sheet1.Cells(4,1) & "TRUE" ")"

Sheet1.Cells(34,14).FormulaArray = tempStr
also tried 
Sheet1.Range("N34:P59").FormulaArray = tempStr
```

I get

> Run-time error '1004'

If I first add {} around the function string

```
tempStr = "{=myFunction(""" & Sheet1.Cells(2,1) & """;""" & Sheet1.Cells(3,1) & """;""" & Sheet1.Cells(4,1) & """;""" & Sheet1.Cells(4,1) & "TRUE" ")}"

Sheet1.Cells(34,14).FormulaArray = tempStr
```

it will end up in the cell, but as a string, and if I remove the {} the function will return values as expected. (So the string is correctly created.)

Comment: First, I think you are adding the result of the array, like `=1,2,3` the second, you are adding an array to the cell, like `={1,2,3}`  you can say things like `=INDEX({1,2,3},1,2)` for example.

Comment: You should use commas as separators with the `Formula` property, not semicolons.

Comment: Thank you @Rory!!
Problem solved!